# Firebase Domain Nameservers

Tags: firebase, dns, hosting, firebase-hosting, nameservers

I'm new to Firebase, what I was trying to do is connect my domain with Firebase Hosting, I own a .pk domain and have limited services on domain, as I can just change the nameservers (I do not have access to DNS TXT), It is possible to connect my domain to Firebase using the nameservers?

(Means what are the nameservers of Google Firebase?)

Currently my nameservers are connected to 000webhost's nameservers

Thanks

Comment: how did you do it ? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @FAQi you can use NameCheap free DNS and point your .pk domain DNS to NameCheap and then you can set records in NameCheap.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked around in .pk domain management section and found that they now allow adding "TXT/A/CNAME" records. So i have successfully connected firebase with my .pk domain, directly from .pk's own native domain management section. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must be able to prove ownership of the domain with a TXT record to connect it to Firebase Hosting. However, if you can change the name servers you should be able to point to a different name server (for example, [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/)) and *then* configure TXT records, etc.